# ng-model on select stop working after typing in input

Tags: angularjs

Right now selecting an option in the selectbox updates the input with the selected name, which is what I want. But if type something in the input field and then select another option in the selectbox it stops updating the input. How come?

Here is the code:

```
<div ng-app>
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl">

    <select ng-model="selected" ng-options="box.name for box in selectBoxData">            
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="newSelectValue" value="{{selected.name}}"/>
    <button>Save</button>
</div>
```

```
function TestCtrl($scope) 
{

    $scope.selectBoxData = [
        { 'name': 'test1', 'id': 1 },
        { 'name': 'test2', 'id': 2 },
        { 'name': 'test3', 'id': 3 },
    ];

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/C8hZN/

Comment: you should be using ng-model instead of value on text box

Comment: That will update the select box with the input right away. I want it to only update when clicking the save button

Comment: What is the purpose of the save button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the `value` attribute in the console you'll see that it still updates correctly when the select changes. I think it doesn't display that value because whatever is typed into the box takes precedence over the attribute value.

To get around this I'd set a model on the text box and bind the selected option's name to that. Then when update is pressed, set the selected option's name from the input.

http://jsfiddle.net/C8hZN/3/

Comment: Thanks a lot. Still thinks it would be logically if my code did the same. But not really sure if it as bug or not?

Answer (score 1):

When you use {{selected.name}} in the value attribute of your input box, the value is linked to the selected object, but once you type into the input box, you modify the value so that it is disconnected it from the object reference. That is why future modifications to the select box no longer update the text box.